# Matching date in string

Tags: php, regex

Having difficuties matching a date in the given string. Tried a myriad of regex suggestions. Keep on getting "No date found", while the date is obviously there: 07/02/2016.

What am I missing?

```
function matchDate($str) {
    if (preg_match('/\b(0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)?[0-9]{2}\b/', $str, $mDdate)) {
        return $mDdate[0];
    } else {
        return "No date found.";
    }
}

$str = "FISH HOUSE KINGS FISH HOUSE 100 W Broadway Long Beach, Ca. 90802 562-432-7463 Server: Ezbeth 07/02/2016 Table 44/1 8:38 PM 60018 10.00 18.75 enon Drop Fried atiish D I obster Crunchy Roll callap and Shrimp Char D 13.50 22.50 6.95 101.60 Cheeseburger 1/2lb D (2 14.95) 29.90 Caesar Salad Subtotal Tax 9.14 110.74 110.74 Total Ba 1ance Due KING'S FISH HOUSE Welcome To The House That Seafood Built Find Us Online @KingsFishHouse ";

echo matchDate($str);
```

Comment: Don't try to validate the date components in the `regex`. Write a simple `regex` that identifies strings that contain 2 digits followed by `/`, 2 digits, `/` and another 4 digits then use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to check if it is a valid date or just a strings that follows the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your example regex is that you need to escape the `/` character in the pattern.

If you don't escape the `/` character, regex will understand it as the end of the regex pattern.

Based on your example, the solution should be:
`\b(0?[1-9]|1[012])\/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(19|20)?[0-9]{2}\b`

You can see it in action in [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/bCyNn5/1)

Comment: Or use other delimiters, e.g. `~` where you do not need to escape the `/`.

Comment: I didn't know that (js dev here), thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

For your given example, this is

```
\b\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/l0SbzI/1/).

Comment: +1 for great resource. I'd like to see if I can find a way to match multiple formats in addition to mm/dd/yyyy and that seems to be a great place to start. Thanks.